# How to find eigvals/eigvecs of huge symmetric tridiagonal matrix using multiple processes or threads?

Tags: parallel-computing, sparse-matrix, multicore

In python, there is a function in scipy (`scipy.linalg.eigh_tridiagonal`) which is extremely efficient for an exact diagonalization of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix (I think it uses MRRR algorithm, not sure). But only a single core is assigned to solve the exact diagonalization. Is there a way of using remaining cores to speed up finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Do you want to stick to python? If not, you could embed a language with more support for more scientific computing, such as `C++`, into your current program and make use of one of the many available options, e.g. [Spectra](https://spectralib.org/), [SLEPc](https://slepc.upv.es/) or [blaze](https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze/src/master/).